# Uncaught ReferenceError: [function] is not defined

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

I'm trying to implement Googlemaps in my Page but i'm getting into some problems surly because I'm still new with webdev.

I've followed the google API tutorial on saving data to a database and created the appropriate functions in my .js file.

The code looks like this:

```
    function createMarker(location){

    if(poiMode && activeMarkerIcon != null) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        icon: activeMarkerIcon,
        clickable:true,
        draggable:true,
        animation:null,
        raiseOnDrag:false,
        title: Titel,
        map: map
        });
        useFilter();
    activeGroup.push(marker);  // Marker wird zum dazugehÃ¶rigenArray hinzugefuegt
    map.setOptions({draggableCursor:'default'}) // Mauscursor wieder in ursprÃ¼nglichen Zustand versetzen
    $('body, #poi1, #poi2, #poi3, #poi4, #poi5, #poi6, #poi7, #loeschen').removeClass('poi1A poi2A poi3A poi4A poi5A poi6A poi7A deleteA');
      var html = "<table>" +
      "<tr><td>Name:</td> <td><input type='text' id='name'/> </td> </tr>" +
      "<tr><td>Beschreibung:</td> <td><TEXTAREA id='description' rows='10' cols='50'></TEXTAREA></td> </tr>" +
      "<tr align='right'><td></td><td><input type='button' value='Speichern' onclick='saveData()'/></td> <td><input type='button' value='Abbrechen' onclick='infowindow.close()'/></td> </tr>";
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: html
    });
    poiMode = false;
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event){
        clickOnMarker(marker);
    });
    $('.activeButton').removeClass("activeButton");

    }
}
```

and the saveData() function is in the same .js file and looks like this:

```
     function saveData() {
      var name = escape(document.getElementById("name").value);
      var address = escape(document.getElementById("address").value);
      var latlng = marker.getPosition();

      var url = base_url + "map/addMarker?name=" + name + "&address=" + address + "&description=" + "test" + "&user_id=" + "1" +"&lat=" + latlng.lat() + "&lng=" + latlng.lng() + "&date=" + "" +"&type=" + "poi";
      downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
        if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1) {
          infowindow.close();
          document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Location added.";
        }
      });
}
```

Yet when I press the save Button on my "Form" I get the console error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: saveData is not defined

Could you please tell me, what I'm doing wrong? since I cant see my own error.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Just so that people don't have to hunt around, `saveData` is called in the last line of the stringified HTML in the first function (`createMarker`), as an inline `onclick` handler for an `<input>`.

Comment: Is saveData global or is it scoped in another function? You could try to define your function as a property of the window object. Instead of `function saveData()` it would be `window.saveData = function()`

Comment: check if the InfoWindow is not being rendered inside an iframe.

Comment: the `saveData()` function is in the scope of the `$(document).ready(function() {...});` taking the function out of this scope results in more errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this issue by defining `saveData()` as a function of infowindow

```
infowindow.saveData = function(){
...
});
```

and calling the function with:

```
<input type='button' value='Save' onclick='infowindow.saveData()'/>
```

Thanks basilikum and everyone else!