# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined on gmaps with rails backend

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

**What I read in order to solve the issue:**
I read the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741537/uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined) that actually addressed the same problem, but the solution did not work when I tried to implement it. 
I am following this example [from gooogle maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3), in my implementation.

**The issue:**
when I press the save Button on my "Form" I get the console error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: saveData is not defined
```

I am trying to implement the above on a rails and am using gmaps4rails as the source of my map.

**My code:**

```
  function show_location(lat, lng, mitlocation_id, location_name,bldgnum){
    var infoWindowContent = [
    "<form id='map-form'>",
    "<div>Food Description: <input id='food-description' type='text' /></div>",
    "<input type='button' value='Post Byte' onclick='saveData()'/>",
    "</form>"].join("");   

    var tempmarker= {"lat":lat,
      "lng":lng},
      "infowindow":infoWindowContent
    };

    handler.addMarker(tempmarker);
  };

    function saveData(){
      console.log("hi")
    };
```

both methods are defined under `$(document).ready( function () {...}`, so I am a bit confused of why the saveData method is not defined.

thank you for your help